# How can I get Webshim and Turbolinks to play nice together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, webshim

The webshims for my form work fine on initial page load, but don't after I navigate to another page.

I have tried calling `updatePolyfill` in handlers and it doesn't fix the issue.

```
$.webshim.setOptions ...
$.webshim.polyfill('forms')

// none of these fixes the issue
$(document).on "page:load", ->
    $(this).updatePolyfill()
    $('body').updatePolyfill()
    $('form').updatePolyfill()
    $.webshim.polyfill('forms')

$(document).ready ->
    // same deal (using jquery.turbolinks)
```

How can I load the shims after navigating away from the initial page?

Comment: how did you added polyfill in you document.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar it's in application.js.  The shims are not included but are located in vendor.

Comment: can you just confirm it by putting `alert('foo')` in `$(document).on "page:load" callback`  is it executing ?

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar already confirmed

Comment: so, it is not executing ?

Comment: confirmed the js callback is firing normally

Comment: hmm, then the other thing is you might missed adding `data-turbolinks-track` in desire script link.

Comment: Does it work, if you run $('body').updatePolyfill() in your console after a change happened?